# How do I adjust the line spacing in Pentaho Report Designer when I am using HTML

Tags: html, pentaho

I have some text in a database. Some of this text I need to have italicized, so I have put HTML code around this text in my database.

In order for PRD to display this text as italics, I need to have the `rich-text-type` field in the attribute tab be `text/html`. But when this is done the standard font, line spacing, etc. changes and does not follow what is otherwise listed.

In order to get the font I want, I need to put into the `value` field in the attribute tab some HTML code that calls for particular fonts etc. Here is what I have:

```
<html><body><span style=""font-family: 'Times New Roman'; font-size: 10pt; "">" & [genus_notes] & " <span></body></html>
```

Normally I should be able to add html code to help deal with how large the space is between rows (e.g. line-height: 80%).
For example:

```
 ="<html><body><span style=""font-family: 'Times New Roman'; font-size: 10pt;line-height: 80%; "">" & [genus_notes] & " <span></body></html>"
```

But for some reason, PRD does not seem to understand this bit of code.

The issue is that the default space between lines is too big for what I need and I am not able to adjust it as mentioned above.

Am I doing something wrong?

If this is just a limitation of PRD, does anyone have any workaround ideas of how I can get rich text into my PRD report and at the same time be able to have the space between lines of text to be what I need?

Answer (score 0):

diy you define that the text-field contains html?? you cant try this:[add style format to text-fiel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W6BC9.png), i hope you serve

Comment: Yes I have the style-class set to "text/html". Like I mentioned all the rest of the code works (e.g. font-size and font-family) it is just the line-height that doesn't seem to respond.

Comment: I think I found the solution to your problem, look here http://forums.pentaho.com/showthread.php?79490-Line-spacing-setting-in-the-Pentaho-Report,I hope you serve, have good day

Comment: When the style-class is set to "text/html", which I need to do in order to have the imported data read as html code, all of the other formatting doesn't respond. Such as what is pointed to in that link. So this "solution" doesn't work.